# Error in rewrite cobol

Tags: cobol

I have the code,

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. SAMPLE3.                           

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
  SELECT EMP-SALARY ASSIGN TO 'input.txt'            
  ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
  ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL.                  
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.                                    
FD EMP-SALARY.                                     
01  NEWFILE.                                     
05  FS-EMPNO  PIC 9(6).                      
05  FS-NAME   PIC 9(4).                     
05  FILLER    PIC X(63).                              
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01    WS-EOF     PIC A(1)  VALUE "N".                     
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-PARA.
OPEN I-O  EMP-SALARY                                   
PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT UNTIL WS-EOF="Y"
STOP RUN.  

   MAIN-PARA-EXIT.
EXIT.
   READ-PARA.
 READ EMP-SALARY               
 AT END                       
  MOVE "Y" TO WS-EOF          
 NOT AT END                   
    IF FS-EMPNO > 10000         
       MOVE '1000' TO FS-NAME

       REWRITE NEWFILE    
        DISPLAY " RECORD " NEWFILE
    END-IF 
    END-READ.

 READ-PARA-EXIT.
EXIT.
```

I got the error read statement should be executed first Status=43, and implicit close of file.

This program is to rewrite a record in a file. what is the reason for this error.

Comment: Is this fixed then? How?

Comment: YES.After adding file status  after open statement fixed the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to include FILE STATUS processing for any files you use in a program, and always test the value after an IO.

If that is the code you are running, you must have an OPEN failing, a READ failing, and the REWRITE deciding that it just can't go on. Check that it is the code that you are running.

Can you show the version of GnuCOBOL you are running, and the OS you are running on, include the FILE STATUS in your program and test the values, and also include an explicit CLOSE of your file, which is always good practice.

See if structuring your program like this simplifies:

```
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    OPEN I-O  EMP-SALARY                                   
* do file status checking here
    PERFORM READ-PARA
    PERFORM PROCESS-PARA UNTIL END-OF-INPUT-FILE
* END-OF-INPUT-FILE (make the name relevant to your file) is an 88 on the FILE STATUS 
* filed for that file
* close the file
* do file status checking here
    STOP RUN
    .  
READ-PARA.
    READ EMP-SALARY               
* do file status checking here
PROCESS-PARA.
    IF FS-EMPNO > 10000         
       MOVE '1000' TO FS-NAME
       PERFORM UPDATE-RECORD
    END-IF 
    PERFORM READ-PARA
    .
UPDATE-RECORD.
    REWRITE NEWFILE    
* do file status checking here
    DISPLAY " RECORD " NEWFILE
    .
```